# Find the line of reflection

Tags: linear-algebra

$T\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right] = \frac{-1}{10}\left[\begin{array}{c}8x + 6y \\ 6x- 8y\end{array}\right]$

I know that it's equivalent to

$\frac{-1}{10}\left[\begin{array}{cc}8 & 6 \\ 6 & -8\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right]$

but I'm not sure how to get the equation of the line of reflection.

Comment: If you post the original problem it may be easier to understand what you are asking. I am guessing, since $T$ represents a reflection of vectors in the plane, that you want to find the line across which vectors are reflected. Is that true?

Comment: The only information I left out is asking whether the transformation is a reflection or an angle. And I believe what you said is true. The answer is $y = -3x$ if that helps.

Comment: Yes. That is the answer I get. You find that by solving the equation $Tv=v$. The reason that works is that the line of reflection is the only line that is not moved by the reflection. Points above it are moved below it and vice versa.

Comment: That's a good point about the line not changing after the transformation, but do you mind giving more detail on the calculations?